# Android Studio not showing Flutter Source Code

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to get access to the source of code of a widget however Android Studio is not showing the correct source code as I cannot see the build method that builds that widget. See below:

**This is the widget I'm trying to get access to the source code by using  CTRL+clicking on the widget**

```
FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        child: Icon(Icons.email),
      ),
```

**However I get transfered to this nonesense code with errors, any advise how can I fix this?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm using Android studio 4.0 and same issue. But instead of these Gibberish content, I'm having many '?' letters.

Comment: no, I have not found the solution.